# Call function with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call functions with variables.

So I need to call the function

```
fnGetGroups()
```

In the code below is what is tried.

```
if (data.name == "getChildren"){
     var contentType = "fnGet" + data.context.title;
     console.log(contentType);
     window[contentType](data.context);
}
```

If I console log the variable: contentType it returns "fnGetGroups"

Without defining fnGetGroups() in the global scope

Comment: It should work if `fnGetGroups` is defined in global scope

Comment: And what happens when you run that code? Is there an error in the console, or...?

Comment: do a `console.log(window[contentType]);`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks!!! Worked out :)

Comment: So you mean "using a function with local variables" not "using a function with argument variables"?

Comment: What was wrong?

Comment: @Satpal Is there a way to not define "fnGetGroups" in the global scope? and still call the function with a variable

Comment: Define it in some object i.e. `var obj={fnGetGroups: function(){ ....}}`, then you can use `obj["fnGetGroups"]()`

Comment: @Satpal Or `obj.fnGetGroups()`.

Comment: @Feathercrown, Yep true but OP wants to _call function with variable_ i.e. string literal

Comment: @Satpal Ah, never mind then.

Comment: @Satpal I have my functions in an array now called: ArrayFunction.  I would like to call one of the functions inside the array how can I do this? and make this variable. I tried working with indexOf(contentType) but that did not work

Comment: Post that as a separate question with relevant and share the link